# Get rid of “Bad value X-XRDS-Location for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.” in XHTML5 validation

Tags: html, validation, web

I have [an XHTML 5 page](http://www.shlomifish.org/__Beta-kmor/) served with application/xhtml+xml which I want to get to validate, but the validator gives me trouble in its [validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.shlomifish.org/__Beta-kmor/):

```
Line 17, Column 89: Bad value X-XRDS-Location for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element
```

The line in question is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://shlomif.livejournal.com/data/yadis" />
```

How can I fix this problem? Was an arbitrary "http-equiv" value removed from the XHTML 5 specification?

Comment: what is XHTML5? I only know html5 and xhtml2

Comment: @bwoebi: It's the XML serialization of HTML5. There is no standalone XHTML5 specification however.

Comment: @BoltClock html5 which a xml parser can parse? ok.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up setting it in an Apache "Header" directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (X)HTML5, you may only use `http-equiv` values that are

- [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives), or
- registered in the [WHATWG wiki page "PragmaExtensions"](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

If you think `X-XRDS-Location` would be a useful value, you’d have to [register](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-pragma-directives) it.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.html says:

> Changes in HTML5
>
> Although previous versions of HTML allowed the http-equiv attribute on the meta element to have any number of possible values, the http-equiv attribute is now restricted to only the specific values described in this reference. Also, the new charset attribute is now allowed.

So, yes, it is not allowed anymore.

Comment: @ShlomiFish If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.