# W3C validation error: "Bad value X-XRDS-Location for attribute http-equiv on element meta"

Tags: html, wordpress, w3c-validation, social-authentication, xrds

I am getting the above validation error in response to the following line in my HTML:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/socialauth-wp/hybridauth/index.php?get=openid_xrds" />
```

I use WordPress social auth plugin, that automatically adds this line to the head of every page.

I am not sure what this line does to the site but it throws a validation error.

What does the meta line does to the site, is it mandatory?

I gone through the question
[Get rid of “Bad value X-XRDS-Location for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.” in XHTML5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124335/get-rid-of-bad-value-x-xrds-location-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-xhtml-element), but I'm not sure how to register it.

Answer (score 0):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125308/1591669) to the linked question applies here, too:

If you use HTML5, you may only use the following values for the `http-equiv` attribute:

- those [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives), or
- those [registered in the WHATWG wiki page "PragmaExtensions"](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

`X-XRDS-Location` is not defined/registered, so HTML5 doesn’t allow to use it.

---

> What does the meta line does to the site, is it mandatory?

I guess the linked [XRDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRDS) document is used to discover your OpenID service provider. Or for Oauth, [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRDS#Example_uses).

---

An alternative may be to send the HTTP header `X-XRDS-Location`. If you send it, you could remove the `meta` element (unless some data consumers only look for the occurence in the HTML, which would be a bad practice).