# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> error in W3C validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, meta, w3c-validation, http-equiv

I am using Bootstrap 3.

When I add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`, the site shows error in the W3C validator.

Comment: You could remove it and have something go wrong in IE, or leave it there and fail validation. I know what I'd do.

Answer (score 1):

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125308/1591669) to a similar question:

> In (X)HTML5, you may only use `http-equiv` values that are
>
> - [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives), or
> - registered in the [WHATWG wiki page "PragmaExtensions"](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

The value `X-UA-Compatible` is not defined in the spec, but it’s *proposed* in the wiki. "Proposed" means:

> The following proposed extensions do not yet conform to all the registration requirements in the HTML spec and are therefore not yet allowed in valid documents.

So currently it’s not valid to use this value in (X)HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: And then it won't trigger in IE10 or IE11.

Answer (score 0):

The validator is extremely pedantic. It's best to just ignore this particular validation warning, given its significant pragmatic benefit and complete lack of downsides. It's not an error of any kind in any of the major browsers.