# "Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta"

Tags: html, meta, w3c-validation, http-equiv

Ok so I have been using the wrong code for I don't know how long now - it seems that

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

is wrong and the following is correct

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="mon, 27 sep 2010 14:30:00 GMT">
```

So my question is how do I still get it to be `0` if they want me to put date format like above and how to I generate this without PHP/JavaScript? It seems stupid to put this in date format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 meta Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655526/html5-meta-validation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125308/1591669) to use the `expires` pragma directive in HTML5, as it is [not defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives) nor [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#other-pragma-directives) on the wiki page [PragmaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

Instead, you should use the corresponding HTTP header.

According to [RFC 4229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4229#section-2.1.47), the `Expires` header field is defined in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21), and its definition is pretty clear about the format:

> The format is an absolute date and time as defined by HTTP-date in [section 3.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1); it MUST be in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) date format […]

Note that it also says about the `0` value:

> HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats, especially including the value "0", as in the past (i.e., "already expired").

About what you should do:

> To mark a response as "already expired," an origin server sends an Expires date that is equal to the Date header value.